# Buffer overflow, not expected result

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Hi I am learning about `Buffer Overflow`. For better understanding I wrote one small code to check what is happening, but i did not find anything wrong.

```
char shellcode[] =
        "\xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00"
        "\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
        "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff"
        "\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3";

void main()
{
   int *ret;

   ret = (int *)&ret + 2;
   (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

And Output :

```
[krishna]$ gcc -o testsc testsc.c
[krishna]$ ./testsc
$ exit
[krishna]$
```

Why it is `exit`? Any other way I can check what happening inside when my program is executing.

What else I can try if my approach is not good enough?

Comment: The `$` in front of `exit` tells you that there's another shell.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac... How could I check that another shell?

Comment: did you generate the shellcode yourself?

Comment: Your best bet would be to run test in a disassembler like ollydbg or IDA PRO and breakpoint line by line to see what it does exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a pointer isn't the same as copying a buffer.  You probably meant:

```
memcpy(ret, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));
```

However this isn't a buffer overflow either.  In this case you will attempt to write to the readonly code pages of the program, so you will get an signal or system exception of some type.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer the question but it lets you know what the shellcode does

Your best bet would be to run test program in a disassembler like ollydbg or IDA PRO and breakpoint line by line to see what it does exactly.

I used ConvertShellcode 2.0 which shows the shellcode as assembly and here is what it looks like

Download link to ConvertShellcode.exe http://www.mediafire.com/?rnnqjdyv0nbency

Usage.

```
ConvertShellcode.exe \xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3
```

```
ConvertShellcode 2.0
Copyright (C) 2009 Alain Rioux.  All rights reserved.

Assembly language source code :
***************************************
00000000  jmp 0x2c
00000002  pop esi
00000003  mov dword[esi+0x8],esi
00000006  mov byte[esi+0x7],0x0
0000000a  mov dword[esi+0xc],0x0
00000011  mov eax,0xb
00000016  mov ebx,esi
00000018  lea ecx,[esi+0x8]
0000001b  lea edx,[esi+0xc]
0000001e  int 0x80
00000020  mov eax,0x1
00000025  mov ebx,0x0
0000002a  int 0x80
0000002c  call 0x2
00000031  das
00000032  bound ebp,qword[ecx+0x6e]
00000035  das
00000036  jae 0xa0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdb for debugging and understanding what is happening inside.

```
      gcc -g -o testsc testsc.c

      gdb testsc

      (gdb)break main
      (gdb)print ret
      (gdb)print *ret
```

and go step by step through the code.

Meanwhile you can view the disassembled code by using readelf/objdump
In another terminal,
objdump -xsd testsc

And use the convert shell code as mentioned by SSpoke to see what the shell code will look like in assembly.

Also have a look at assembler code by using

```
          gcc -S testsc.c
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is exit?

`sh` prints `exit` if input is at EOF, for example when `Ctrl` `D` has been pressed; if you didn't do that, there must be some other reason for the EOF.

> Any other way I can check what happening inside when my program is
>   executing.

Since your program has already successfully executed `/bin/sh`, I see no point in checking *inside* your program with a debugger. I'd look at the output of `strace testsc` (that also traces the shell); near the end we should see a `read` call which is supposed to get command line input for `sh`; perhaps from the returned value and error number we can deduce the reason for the EOF, or we could see where the used file descriptor comes from.

By the way, your program compiled with gcc 2.95.3 (x86) works without `sh` exiting immediately.

Answer (score -2):

buffer overflow?

```
char a[8];
strcpy(a, "0123456789");
```